# regarding spring configuration file

Tags: xml, spring

i am using MyEclipse 8.6.1:
      this is my applicationContext.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">


<bean id="addr" class="info.inetsolv.Address" abstract="false"
    lazy-init="default" autowire="default" dependency-check="default"
    p:street="bk guda" p:city="hyd" p:state="ap">
</bean></beans>
```

This is my java program:
    package info.inetsolv;

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

public class MyAppSprContnr {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml");  
  BeanFactory container= new XmlBeanFactory(resource);
  System.out.println("container"+container);
}

}
```

This is the exception i am getting

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger      (org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main"       org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 11 in XML   document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'dependency-check' is not   allowed to appear in element 'bean'.
at org.springframework.b
```

how to resolv this?

Answer (score 5):

The `dependency-check` attribute has been deprecated since Spring `3.0`. The following workarounds can provide equivalent functionality

- Use constructors (constructor injection instead of setter injection) exclusively to ensure the right properties are set.
- Create setters with a dedicated init method implemented.
- Create setters with `@Required` annotation when the property is required.
- Use `@Autowired`-driven injection which also implies a required property by default.

Related: [@Required example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-dependency-checking-with-required-annotation/)

Answer (score 0):

I agree dependency got deprecated in spring 3, but I tested till spring 4, and it got removed in Spring 5.

I prefer using @Required annotation, because of demerits of dependency-check, as it considers all of the components as mandatory which might be required in all the cases.